If every function is continuous if and only if its projections are continuous, can we conclude the codomain has the product topology?
Let, for each $i\in I$,  $\left(X,\mathcal{O}_\mathcal{X}\right)$ and $\left(Y_i,\mathcal{O}_{\mathcal{Y}_\mathcal{i}}\right)$ be topological spaces.
Does the following equivalence hold:
$$\mathcal{O}\text{ product topology on  }\times_{i\in I}Y_i  \\⇔  \\
\bigg(
∀f:\left(X,\mathcal{O}_\mathcal{X}\right)\rightarrow\left(\times_{i\in I}Y_i,\mathcal{O}\right):  f \text{ continuous }⇔ ∀i∈I: π_i∘f \text{continuous}
\bigg)
$$
The direction $\Rightarrow$ is commonly known.
For the direction $\Leftarrow$ I could show that whatever topology $\mathcal O$ may be, it has the property that a function $f:\left(X,\mathcal{O}_\mathcal{X}\right)\rightarrow\left(\times_{i\in I}Y_i,\mathcal{O}\right)$
is continuous if and only if it is continuous if we replace $\mathcal O$ with the product topology on $\times_{i\in I} Y_i$.
But that doesn't necessarily mean that $\mathcal O$ must be the product topology, does it?

For the $\impliedby$ direction, do you intend for the hypothesis to be quantified over all topological spaces $X$? This seems to be the more interesting question, and appears to be the one addressed by the current answer. Otherwise, if we set $X$ to be discrete, all functions and their projections are continuous regardless of the topology on the product.

I think I've worked out  my misconceptions now and understood what exactly I was hoping to find out. I initially expected, since the direction $\Rightarrow$ doesn't depend on fixing $X$ or its topology, that it wouldn't matter in the reverse direction as well. With  me only being able to show a somewhat related statement for $\Leftarrow$, I also guessed that the answer would be something like "$\mathcal O$ and the product topology are identical up to ...". Your example with the discrete topology clearly showed that, without further constraints, that won't work.

With all this figured out, the current answer (probably) nicely finishes the puzzle, as to what restriction we could choose. Since I'm not familiar with category theory, it will probably take me some time and reading up to understand it

Your question is misleading because it seems that you work with a fixed $\left(X,\mathcal{O}_\mathcal{X}\right)$. Then it can't be true. What you can prove is this:
$$\mathcal{O}\text{ product topology on  }\times_{i\in I}Y_i  \tag{1}$$
$$\Leftrightarrow$$
$$\forall (X,\mathcal{O}_\mathcal{X}) \forall f:\left(X,\mathcal{O}_\mathcal{X}\right)\rightarrow\left(\times_{i\in I}Y_i,\mathcal{O}\right) :  f \text{ continuous }⇔ ∀i∈I: π_i∘f \text{ continuous} \tag{2}$$
As you say, $(1) \implies (2)$ is well-known.
Let us prove  $(2) \implies (1)$.
Let $\mathcal{O}$ be a topology on $\left(\times_{i\in I}Y_i,\mathcal{O}\right)$ such that $(2)$ is satisfied.

The projections $\pi_i : (\times_{i\in I}Y_i,\mathcal{O}) \to (Y_i,\mathcal{O}_{\mathcal{Y}_\mathcal{i}})$ are continuous.

To see this, take $(X,\mathcal{O}_\mathcal{X})= (\times_{i\in I}Y_i,\mathcal{O})$ and  $f = id : (\times_{i\in I}Y_i,\mathcal{O}) \to (\times_{i\in I}Y_i,\mathcal{O})$ which is continuous.

$\mathcal{O}$ is finer than the product topology $\mathcal{O}_{prod}$.

By 1. all $\pi_i^{-1}(U_i)$ with $U_i \in \mathcal{O}_{\mathcal{Y}_\mathcal{i}}$ belong to $\mathcal{O}$. These sets form the usual subbasis for the product topology, thus $\mathcal{O}_{prod} \subset \mathcal{O}$.

$\mathcal{O}_{prod}$ is finer than $\mathcal{O}$.

Take $(X,\mathcal{O}_\mathcal{X})= (\times_{i\in I}Y_i,\mathcal{O}_{prod})$ and  $f = id : (\times_{i\in I}Y_i,\mathcal{O}_{prod}) \to (\times_{i\in I}Y_i,\mathcal{O})$. Since all $\pi_i = \pi_i \circ id$ are continuous, we get that $id : (\times_{i\in I}Y_i,\mathcal{O}_{prod}) \to (\times_{i\in I}Y_i,\mathcal{O})$ is continuous which is nothing else than 3.
Update.
Let us observe that $(2)$ is equivalent to the following property $(3)$ with two parts
$(3.1)$
All projections $\pi_i : (\times_{i\in I}Y_i,\mathcal{O}) \to (Y_i,\mathcal{O}_{\mathcal{Y}_\mathcal{i}})$ are continuous.
$(3.2)$
$\forall (X,\mathcal{O}_\mathcal{X}) \forall f:\left(X,\mathcal{O}_\mathcal{X}\right)\rightarrow\left(\times_{i\in I}Y_i,\mathcal{O}\right) : \text{All } π_i∘f \text{ continuous} \implies f \text{ continuous}.$
In fact, $(2) \implies (3.2)$ is trivial and $(2) \implies (3.1)$ was shown in 1. above. $(3) \implies (2)$ is obvious because by $(3.1)$ we conclude that $f$ continuous implies that all $\pi_i \circ f$ are continuous.
The proof of 3. above shows that any topologies $\mathcal O, \mathcal O'$ satisfying $(3)$ agree. In other words, there exists at most one topology satisfying $(3)$.
The existence of such a topology is well-known: Take the product topology.

This is true.
Here's one way to see this, using a bit of category theory: Let $F\colon \mathrm{Top}^\mathrm{op} \to \mathrm{Set}$ be the (contravariant) functor from the category of topological spaces to that of sets given by
$$
    F(X) := \prod_{i \in I} \mathrm{Top}(X, Y_i)
$$
on objects and by taking a morphism $f\colon Y \to X$ in $\mathrm{Top}$ to precomposition with $f$ in each factor of the product (here $\mathrm{Top}(X, Y)$ denotes the set of all morphisms $f\colon X \to Y$ in $\mathrm{Top}$). The (commonly known) $\Rightarrow$ direction then says that there is an isomorphism
$$
    \mathrm{Top}\bigg(X, \big(\prod_{i \in I} Y_i, \mathcal{O}\big)\bigg) \cong F(X)
$$
for any space $X$ when $\mathcal{O}$ is the product topology (I'll use the somewhat more standard $\prod_{i \in I} Y_i$ over $\times_{i \in I} Y_i$ throughout), and in fact this isomorphism is natural since it's given by sending a morphism $f\colon X \to \prod_{i \in I} Y_i$ to the tuple $(\pi_i \circ f)_{i \in I} \in F(X)$ and the action of both functors on morphisms is by precomposition.
On the other hand, if we assume the condition in the back direction holds for some topology $\mathcal{O}'$ on $\prod_{i \in I} Y_i$, then this amounts to saying that there is a natural isomorphism
$$
    \mathrm{Top}\bigg(X, \big(\prod_{i \in I} Y_i, \mathcal{O}'\big)\bigg) \cong F(X)
$$
for any space $X$ of the same form, after noting that the projection maps $\pi_i$ are continuous which follows from plugging in $\big(\prod_{i \in I} Y_i, \mathcal{O}'\big)$ for $X$, by the same argument. In other words, $\big(\prod_{i \in I} Y_i, \mathcal{O}\big)$ and $\big(\prod_{i \in I} Y_i, \mathcal{O}'\big)$ represent the same functor $F$, so they must be uniquely isomorphic in $\mathrm{Top}$ (i.e. homeomorphic) in a way compatible with the natural isomorphisms above, from which it follows that this isomorphism must be the  identity (on the set level) on $\prod_{i \in I} Y_i$ (I'll leave this as exercise, but let me know if you need more details).

Unluckily, I'm not familiar with category theory, so I can't judge your answer fairly. The style of argument looks very interesting though, unlike any I am used to, so I'll try reading up on it!

You have a little gap.  You can only define $\beta : \mathbf{Top}\bigg(X, \big(\prod_{i \in I} Y_i, \mathcal{O}\big)\bigg) \to F(X)$ by $\beta(f) = (\pi_i \circ f)_{i \in I}$ if you know that the $\pi_i$ are continuous. This is the case for the product topology, but for an arbitrary topology $\mathcal{O}$ with the property as in the question you must prove it. This is almost trivial (see Paul Frost's answer), but it should be explicitly mentioned.

@ConnFus: There’s just one idea from category theory needed here: “Given two objects $P$, $P'$ of some category, if for all other objects $X$ maps $X \to P$ correspond naturally to maps $X \to P'$, then $P$ and $P'$ are isomorphic.” — informally, “an object is determined by all the maps into it”.  Formally this is the Yoneda lemma; concretely its proof is just what Paul Frost’s answer spells out: take the map $P \to P'$ corresponding to the identity $P \to P$, and vice versa; these give an isomorphism.

@KritikerderElche Thank you for pointing this out!

@ConnFus I warmly recommend reading about it if you have the time! As Peter LeFanu Lumsdaine points out, the keyword here is "Yoneda lemma," and it's a very useful technique to decide questions like this in general.
